# Stacked bar chart with 100 percent width using HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

How do I create the bar chart below? There are two versions. Thank you.

[image: chart with 100 percent width using HighCharts]

Comment: your question is not clear. can you explain more?

Comment: Do you see the images?

Comment: Yes i do, but i dont see any difference

Comment: Agree, just the emphasized color is aligned left or right. I am playing with this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tPw24/534/

Comment: you want the output to be like 2nd image?

Comment: I need both charts to be separated and exactly same look and feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result with a stacked bar chart. Two series - one with the actual data, and the other for filling a bar and keeping labels. You should normalize the data your own (setting complementary values for the second series and min/max for axis).

```
    series: [{
  color: 'green',
  data: [5, 3, 1],
  dataLabels: {
    align: 'right',
    format: '{point.y} %'
  }
}, {
  color: 'grey',
  data: [{
    y: 3,
    label: 'Footbal'
  }, {
    y: 5,
    label: 'Soccer'
  }, {
    y: 7,
    label: 'Baseball'
  }],
  dataLabels: {
    align: 'left',
    format: '{point.label}'
  }
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tPw24/553/

For the second chart, just swap the colors and data: http://jsfiddle.net/tPw24/555/

Comment: First one is good, but I think the second one isn't. The %s aren't correct. Do you have an idea how to fix that? thanks

Comment: Actually, I configured your second solution even further. Now it looks good. Thank you for help.

http://jsfiddle.net/tPw24/558/